# How to delete column in 2d array c++ with dynamic array?

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I want to delete column with max integer in 2d array, I do it in this way, but why is deleting the column and also row? Can I fix that and delete only column? The task was do it with delete command, but now I think it's impossible

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int row = 3, col = 3;
int** arr = new int* [row];
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    arr[i] = new int[col];
}
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        cin >> arr[i][j];
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
    cout << " ------------- " << endl;

int max = 0, index = 0;
for(int i =0; i < row; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
        if(arr[i][j] > max){
            max = arr[i][j];
            index = i;
        }
    }
}
delete [] arr[index];
int** tmp = new int*[index - 1];
int tmpI = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < col; i++){
    if(i != index){
        tmp[tmpI++] = arr[i];
    }
}
delete [] arr;
arr = tmp;
col = col - 1;

for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

}
```

Comment: I recommend using `std::vector`

Comment: `index` is a row index, not a column index. But inexplicably, the loop that copies into `tmp`  runs while `i < col`, not while `i < row` like it's everywhere else. It's unclear what you are trying to do there.

Comment: Also, `int** tmp = new int*[index - 1];` doesn't make sense. E.g. what if `index == 0` - the largest value is in the very first row?

Comment: 1d array with some math on indexes is the best representation of 2d array

Comment: Your code is flawed. You are deleting a row and not a column. Deleting a column in your 2D array is not possible by using only 1 `delete[]` statement. Your 2D array has **3** rows. Each of those rows has to first be copied to a temporary 1D array and then be deleted and then be created using `new int[3 - 1]` and be replaced with the previous row's pointer. Then the content of the temp 1D array has to be copied back to the newly created row, excluding the column that has to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the variable index is set to a row number

```
index = i;
```

Then this row is deleted

```
delete [] arr[index];
```

But you are going to remove a column instead of a row. So this code does not make a sense.

Also you are incorrectly searching the maximum element. If the user will enter all negative values then the maximum value will be equal to 0 though an element with such value is not present in the array.

In this declaration

```
int** tmp = new int*[index - 1];
```

you allocated an array with rows that one less than the number of rows in the original array. Moreover if index is equal to 0 then there is allocated a very large extent of memory.

This statement

```
delete [] arr;
```

produces a memory leak.

It seems what you need is something like the following

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    size_t row = 3, col = 3;
    
    int **arr = new int * [row];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        arr[i] = new int[col];
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < col; j++ ) 
        {
            std::cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < col; j++ ) 
        {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << "------------- " << std::endl;
    
    size_t max_i = 0, max_j = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < col; j++ )
        {
            if ( arr[max_i][max_j] < arr[i][j] )
            {
                max_i = i; max_j = j;
            }
        }
    }
    
    int **tmp = new int*[row];
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        tmp[i] = new int[col-1];
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0, k = 0; j < col; j++ )
        {
            if ( j != max_j ) tmp[i][k++] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        delete [] arr[i];
    }
    
    delete [] arr;
    
    arr = tmp;
    
    --col;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < col; j++ ) 
        {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
        delete [] arr[i];
    }
    
    delete [] arr;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
1 2 3 
6 5 4 
7 9 8 
 ------------- 
1 3 
6 4 
7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate suggestion: You are storing the data in `row x column` format. If you change to `column x row` format, it becomes easier to delete a column. I also made a helper function to print the matrix and I combined the input loop and the loop that finds the max.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>  // for rand
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

void print_matrix(int** arr, int rows, int columns)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
            cout << setw(2) << arr[col][row] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(nullptr));  // For testing
    
    int rows = 3, columns = 3;
    
    // Create the matrix
    int** arr = new int *[columns];
    for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
        arr[col] = new int[rows];
    }
    
    // Input values - finding max, too
    int max_value = INT_MIN, max_value_column = -1;
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
            //cin >> arr[col][row];
            arr[col][row] = rand() % 50;    // Using rand for testing.
            if (arr[col][row] > max_value) {
                max_value = arr[col][row];
                max_value_column = col;
            }
        }
    }   
    print_matrix(arr, rows, columns);
    cout << " ------------- " << endl;

    // Delete the column with max
    delete [] arr[max_value_column];
    columns--;
    // Shift columns to the right of the deleted column left one
    for (int col = max_value_column; col < columns; col++) {
        arr[col] = arr[col + 1];
    }
    print_matrix(arr, rows, columns);

    return 0;
}
```